# What's the meaning of "took to" in “Democrats took to the Senate floor to protest the legislation. ”

Tags: phrase-usage

What's the meaning of "**took to**" in “Democrats **took to** the Senate floor to protest the legislation.”

Looked up in a dictionary, but can not find any meaning that can reflect to the meaning in the context. I see that explanation "to start to use or do something as a habit", but it seems that it's not quite right in this context – that “as a habit” part confuses me.

Dictionaries interpret the phase "take to" with the sense of "a habit". eg. "Begin or fall into the habit of" in Oxford, "begin to do it as a regular habit" in the dictionary on my phone. So, I am not sure what will be correct usage of "take to" in this context.

Comment: Oh, it's very much there in the dictionaries...
Cambridge:
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-to-something, 
MacMillan:
http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-to
OxfordLearners
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/take-to

These links should help you understand the meaning. If not, comment back with your understanding.

Comment: I did see that explanation  "to start to use or do something as a habit", but it seems that it's not quite right in this context.

Comment: "Begin to do something"/"To start to use" is the correct explanation here. Earlier, the Democrats might have been protesting the legislation in other ways, but now, the Democrats have 'started to use' the Senate floor to protest against the legislation. In other words, they have brought the protest against the legislation to the Senate floor.

Comment: Originally, I see "... as a habit" which confused me in this context.

Comment: No, "... as a habit" is not the correct meaning of "took to" in this context.

Comment: but if you looked into some other dictionaries, they all interpret the phase "take to" with the sense of "a habit". eg. "Begin or fall into the habit of" in Oxford, "begin to do it as a regular habit" in the dictionary on my phone. So, I am not sure what will be correct usage of "take to" in this context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62962/discussion-between-satnam-and-dan).

Comment: @dan - You are telling us what you found and why it confused you in the comments. You really should do that in your question. That way, people won’t be sending you links to dictionaries you’ve already visited. [More advice at this meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: Keep looking up the vocabulary unit in [multiple dictionaries](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/739/3395) until you've found a fitting definition. I don't know much about American politics, but I don't interpret it as "begin to do something" exactly, @satnam. Instead, as per the OALD, for example, it means to turn to something, avail oneself of someone's help, "to go away to a place, especially to escape from danger". But anyway, since this question is entirely answerable by a dictionary, I recommend it be closed as such.

Comment: For someone who already understands the phrase, sorting out the dictionary definitions seems straightforward and can provide the gist.  However, the dictionary definitions don't lend themselves to precisely understanding the meaning intended in this context.  @satnam, you've done a good job of explaining it in the comments.  Consider moving that to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression **take to the streets** is probably closest to the intended meaning of **take to** in this context:

> of a crowd of people) To gather together in the public streets of a town or city to show communal solidarity in either celebration or opposition. [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/take-to-the-streets)

So, what it means in your context is that the Democrats in the Senate gathered together to protest the legislation.